# Swift. Create an intro video when app launches

Tags: swift, video, sprite-kit, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I want to play a local video as an intro video, when my app launches. The user should not be able to cancel the video or pause it in any way any idea how I can do that?

```
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class GetInfoView: SKScene {

    var moviePlayer = AVPlayerViewController()
    var player = AVPlayer()

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        player = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("intro", ofType: "mp4")!))
        moviePlayer.showsPlaybackControls = false
        moviePlayer.player = player

        self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(moviePlayer, animated: false){
        moviePlayer.player?.play()
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried this, but when it runs `player = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("intro", ofType: "mp4")!))` It crashes.

The error:

```
"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"
```

I don't know what the problem is, and I did add "intro.mp4" to my build

[image]

Comment: It looks like it isn't finding intro.mp4

Comment: Yeah, and I don't know why it isn't finding it because I did add it to the build, I updated my questing ;)

Comment: Did you add the video to your target? (Click on that video file, look at File Inspector on the right side in Xcode, and see if the "Target Membership" box has the checkbox next to your target selected)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add your movies project.File Inspector -> Project name -> Targets -> Project Name -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources -> + button